# Im trying to make a soundboard

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

whenever i select my audio capture device i get the error

```
   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
    HResult=0x88890003
    Message=0x88890003
    Source=NAudio.Wasapi
    StackTrace:
     at NAudio.CoreAudioApi.AudioClient.get_AudioRenderClient()
     at NAudio.Wave.WasapiOut.Init(IWaveProvider waveProvider)
   at SoundFish.Form1.listBoxSounds_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) in       C:\Users\user\source\repos\SoundFish\SoundFish\Form1.cs:line 183
   at System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.WmReflectCommand(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, WM msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

i haven't been able to fix this either

I've tried changing the capture device, retarting my pc, making it where there was no apps using my mic
none worked

Comment: You'll need to show us the code that generates this error (along with any values that you are using). Read up on how to create a [mre]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.